# C# DependencyProperty - How does a property get mapped to an object

Tags: c#, dependency-properties, internal

I made a bit research about Dependency Properties and came to a litte confusion.
How does the runtime determine to which object the DependencyProperty belongs?

Imagine a Collection of objects (of the same type) that all register the same DependencyProperty. the Property Is Bound to a TextBox and the TexBoxes are displayed one below the other.

First: is each TextBox bound to a different DependencyProperty? I guess so but im not 100% sure.
Second: If so, how does the runtime determine the object to which the DependencyProperty should get mapped. When registering a DependencyProperty i only specify the object type, in the example MyClockControl. Since there is no solid way of retrieving the calling instance from a called method i just dont get how the object is resolved that "contains" the property and the correct of multiple properties is returned when accessing the dependencyproperty.

Example from http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html

```
// Dependency Property
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentTimeProperty = 
     DependencyProperty.Register( "CurrentTime", typeof(DateTime),
     typeof(MyClockControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));

// .NET Property wrapper
public DateTime CurrentTime
{
    get { return (DateTime)GetValue(CurrentTimeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CurrentTimeProperty, value); }
}
```

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

The `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods (of a `DependencyObject`) get and set the value in a dictionary (well... kind of), declared on `DependencyObject`, **the dependency property being the key**. That means the value corresponding to the `DependencyProperty` is specific to the instance of the `DependencyObject`.